# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints meaning

Tags: swift

what is the use of that translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints I didn't get any idea even I referred so many stuff
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Before the AutoLayout constraint system was introduced, we had the springs and struts layout system on iOS and macOS.  You configured this system by setting the `autoresizingMask` property on a `UIView` type.  If the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property is `true` the system will create AutoLayout constraints matching the old style layout settings on a view, which can lead to unwanted behavior / extra constraints.

As you can read in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco), if a view is created in a storyboard the value of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` should be `false` by default, but if it is created in code this value will be `true` by default.